# Boolean equality

Tags: javascript, boolean, logic

I got this out of an exam question, and couldn't understand how the solution works. This function is supposed to return "true" if the values "x" and "y" are equal, and return False otherwise.

The solution:

```
function equal_boolean (x , y) {
  return x ? y : y ? x : true;
}
```

Why does this work? As much as I can understand, it would turn out to be evaluating if X is true. If X is true, it would return Y. How is X supposed to be "true"?

If it isn't, it would evaluate whether Y is true, if it's true it would return X, and if it isn't - it would return True.

Is there something wrong with my understanding?

Comment: Just: `return x === y;`

Comment: @dfsq his question was for understanding an exercise, not how to be more efficient.

Comment: The important thing to know here is that in a conditional expression in javascript (such as in the first part of the ternary) a standalone reference or literal is implicitely converted to a boolean value. The ternary then more explicitely reads `!! x ? y : !! y ? x : true;`. This is not a working equality test though as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/7wamf2x9/1/ (the return type is neither always a boolean value, nor a correct result).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return x ? y : y ? x : true;
```

parses as

```
if x
   return y       // if y is true, then x == y. if y is false, then x != y
else (x is false)
   if y
      return x    // x is false and y is true, y != x, return false
   else
      return true // x is false and y is false, return true
```

This is of course a pretty convoluted way to express boolean equality (aka [Logical biconditional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional) aka `iff`). More natural would be an expression like this:

```
 (x && y) || (!x && !y)
```

Comment: Much better than mine. :( ... :)

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you should do is group the ternary operators together:

```
(x ? y : (y ? x : true))
```

- if `x` is `true`, then return `y`, whose value also tells you whether `x` and `y` are equal
- if `x` is `false`, then start with the second ternary:

  - if `y` is `true`, then return `x` (`false`) as the two are not equal
  - if `y` is `false`, then `x` and `y` are equal, so return `true`

Answer (score 0):

Let's try expanding this a bit:

```
var myBool = x ? y : (y ? x : true)

return myBool;
```

First block

```
x ? y : ...
```

if X is true, then return value of Y. If Y happens to be true, both are equal. Otherwise return false (no match).

Second block if X was false:

```
y ? x : true
```

if Y is true, return X. X was false, so false is returned (no match)
if Y is false, return true - both values are false.

Answer (score 0):

- First identify the expressions

  ```
  return x ? y : y ? x : true;
  //turns into
  return x ? y : (y ? x : true);
  ```
- Replace the `?:` ternary operators by `if` statements

  ```
  if (x) {
      return y;
  } else {
      //here x is false, so we will be able to replace x by false in the next step
      if (y) {
          return x;
      } else {
          return true;
      }
  }
  ```
- Make `if` statements more verbose, replace `return x` by `return false`

  ```
  if (x == true) {
      return y;
  } else {
      if (y == true) {
          return false;
      } else {
          return true;
      }
  }
  ```
- Finally replace `return y;` by `if (y == true) { return true; } else { return false; }`, and check all the possibilities

  ```
  if (x == true) {
      if (y == true) {
          return true; // x == true and y == true
      } else {
          return false; // x == true and y == false
      }
  } else {
      if (y == true) {
          return false; // x == false and y == true
      } else {
          return true; // x == false and y == false
      }
  }
  ```

It works. (As long as x and y are booleans)